# How to make nested enum also have value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code example:

```
from enum import Enum

class Location(Enum):
    Outside = 'outside'
    Inside = 'inside' 
    class Inside(Enum): # TypeError for conflicting names
        Downstairs = 'downstairs'
        Upstairs = 'upstairs'
```

How do I make Inside have the value 'inside' whilst also being a nested enum for accessing Downstairs and Upstairs?

Desired input:

```
print(Location.Inside)
print(Location.Inside.value)
print(Location.Inside.Downstairs)
print(Location.Inside.Downstairs.value)
```

Desired output:

```
Location.Inside
inside
Location.Inside.Downstairs
downstairs
```

UPDATE 1:

Some more context to my specific problem:

```
class Location(Enum):
    Outside = 'outside'
    Inside = 'inside' 
    class Inside(Enum): # TypeError for conflicting names
        Downstairs = 'downstairs'
        Upstairs = 'upstairs'

class Human:
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location

def getLocationFromAPI():
    # this function returns either 'inside' or 'outside'
    # make calls to external API  
    return location # return location from api in str

def whereInside(human):
    if human.location != Location.Inside:
        return None
    # here goes logic that determines if human is downstairs or upstairs
    return locationInside # return either Location.Downstairs or Location.Upstairs


location_str = getLocationFromAPI() # will return 'inside' or 'outside'
location = Location(location_str) # make Enum
human = Human(location) # create human with basic location
if human.location == Location.Inside:
    where_inside = whereInside(human)
    human.location = where_inside # update location to be more precise
```

The problem is when I create the Human object I only know of a basic location, as in 'inside' or 'outside'. Only after that can I update the location to be more precise.

Comment: Enum's can only have one value.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Aha, thank you. Do you know any other design choice for the code I posted? I think it's quite clear what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me, but how about just removing `Inside = 'inside'`

Comment: Fundamentally what you are asking for doesn't make sense, attributes of any object can only have a single value, and an attribute cannot both be the string `'inside'` and an enum, `Inside`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That would be the best choice but I would have liked for Inside to also have a value so I can make use of the enum property: Location('inside') -> Location.Inside

Comment: `Location.Inside` *does* have a value, it is the nested enum.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know it does not make fundamentally sense and was looking for a hacky solution. Because the only one I can think of is setting the __repr__ to return 'inside' in the Inside class as well as override __getattr__ in the Location class.

Comment: But that won't give you `Location('inside') -> Location.Inside`, which seems to be fundamentally what you want, if I understand you correctly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thats the property i'm looking for yes. And I see now that it's not possible without writing my own interpretation of an Enum class or rethink my design choice. Thanks for all the help and fast responses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can accomplish this by embedding an `Enum` inside another like so: *(just watch out for names conflicting)*

```
from enum import Enum

class _Inside(Enum):
    Downstairs = 'downstairs'
    Upstairs = 'upstairs'

class Location(Enum):
    Outside = 'outside'
    Inside = _Inside 
    
print(Location.Inside.value.Downstairs.value)
downstairs
```

Comment: This is a lot neater than having a nested solution, however, it doesn't help in my particular design since I won't be able to make use of this: Location('inside') -> Location.Inside

Comment: Please be more elaborate as to how you will be using this as this seems to be the best way to answer your question.

Comment: I see your edit, why not use named tuples or even a dict here? Seemed as though you could. Also, your error seems to be due to the fact that you are using Inside then making a class called Inside. Just using Named tuples or a dict would potentially circumvent this

Answer (score 2):

it may be a bit late and the one who asked the question is no longer necessary, but I leave it here in case someone wants to take a look at it, and even if it has already been validated as one, although the same comment that it is not completely complete .

But I have been thinking about it and in the end I have solved it by looking at the same documentation XD.

You cannot extend classes of Enums, but you can extend methods, I have followed this way and the only thing I have done has been to override the **new** and **init** methods, the use case can be modified, this is only to nest enumerators.

```
from enum import Enum

class SuperNestedEnum(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        value = None
        # Normal Enumerator definition
        if len(args) == 1:
            value = args[0]

        # Have a tuple of values, first de value and next the nested enum (I will set in __init__ method)
        if len(args) == 2:
            value = args[0]

        if value:
            obj._value_ = value

        return obj

    def __init__(self, name, nested=None):
        # At this point you can set any attribute what you want
        if nested:
            # Check if is an Enumerator you can comment this if. if you want another object
            if isinstance(nested, EnumMeta):
                for enm in nested:
                    self.__setattr__(enm.name, enm)


class Homework(Enum):
    Task = "5"

class Subjects(SuperNestedEnum):
    Maths = "maths"
    English = "english"
    Physics = "nested", Homework

class School(SuperNestedEnum):
    Name = "2"
    Subjects = "subjects", Subjects
```

Ignore the use case because it doesn't make sense, it's just an example

```
>>> School.Name
<School.Name: '2'>

>>> School.Subjects
<School.Subjects: 'subjects'>

>>> School.Subjects.value
'subjects'

>>> School.Subjects.Maths
<Subjects.Maths: 'maths'>

>>> School.Subjects.Physics.value
'nested'

>>> School.Subjects.Physics.Task
<Homework.Task: '5'>

>>> School.Subjects.Physics.Task.value
'5'
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has similar issues and just wants a simple solution for the topic without patching any functions or additional imports for **enums containing strings**, follow these steps:

1. **Create the value enums**, in your **lower hierarchy**, like:

   ```
   class __private_enum1__(str, enum.Enum):
       VAL11 = "abc"
       VAL12 = "def"

   class enum2(str, enum.Enum):
       VAL21 = "123"
       VAL22 = "456"
   ```
2. **Create a base class** (a container) for these enums. Where you can either import the enums classes or simply directly acccess the enums.

   ```
    class myValues:
        VAL11 = __private_enum1__.VAL11
        VAL12 = __private_enum1__.VAL12
        VALS2X = enum2
   ```

**Then** you can access your values by:

```
print(myValues.VAL11.value)
print(myValues.VAL2X.VAL21.value)
```

`.value` is not necessary here but it shows that you both access the string inside the enum for passing it to other functions but also the enum itself, which is pretty neat. So basically, first create the values, then the structure. That way you have a class but it provides you the basic functionality of enums and you can nest them as deep as you want to without further imports.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer to the question, but still on the same topic. I was looking for some kind of nested Enum but it ended up using just a regular class with class-variables and StrEnum such as:

```
from enum import StrEnum


class _Inside(StrEnum):
    Downstairs = "downstairs"
    Upstairs = "upstairs"


class Location:
    Outside = "outside"
    Inside = _Inside


print(Location.Inside.Downstairs)
```

It also works good with IntEnum, but if you are using Enum, you would have to also call the .value-property to get the actual value as:

```
print(Location.Inside.Downstairs.value)
```